# error when Intalling linux kernel on ubuntu 16.04; dpkg: error processing package linux-tools

Tags: system-installation, kernel, dpkg, compiling

I am following [this tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) to compile and install a new kernel in my ubuntu system and I got this error

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-tools-4.4.0-119-generic (--install)
```

when i issued `sudo dpkg -i linux*4.4.0-119.143*.deb`

This is the complete output:

```
(Reading database ... 270468 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-119_4.4.0-119.143+test1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-119 (4.4.0-119.143+test1) over (4.4.0-119.143+test1) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-119-generic_4.4.0-119.143+test1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143+test1) over (4.4.0-119.143+test1) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.4.0-119_4.4.0-119.143+test1_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-119 (4.4.0-119.143+test1) over (4.4.0-119.143+test1) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic_4.4.0-119.143+test1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143+test1) over (4.4.0-119.143+test1) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic_4.4.0-119.143+test1_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143+test1) over (4.4.0-119.143+test1) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
Preparing to unpack linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic_4.4.0-119.143+test1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143+test1) over (4.4.0-119.143+test1) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-tools-4.4.0-119_4.4.0-119.143+test1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-4.4.0-119 (4.4.0-119.143+test1) over (4.4.0-119.143+test1) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-tools-4.4.0-119-generic_4.4.0-119.143+test1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143+test1) over (4.4.0-119.143+test1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-119:
 linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-119 depends on linux-cloud-tools-common; however:
  Package linux-cloud-tools-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-119 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-119-generic:
 linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-119-generic depends on linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-119; however:
  Package linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-119 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-119-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-119 (4.4.0-119.143+test1) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143+test1) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143+test1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Not updating initrd symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(4.4.0-119.143+test1 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Not updating image symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(4.4.0-119.143+test1 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
Setting up linux-image-extra-4.4.0-119-generic (4.4.0-119.143+test1) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/vboxadd 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-119-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-tools-4.4.0-119:
 linux-tools-4.4.0-119 depends on linux-tools-common; however:
  Package linux-tools-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-tools-4.4.0-119 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-tools-4.4.0-119-generic:
 linux-tools-4.4.0-119-generic depends on linux-tools-4.4.0-119; however:
  Package linux-tools-4.4.0-119 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-tools-4.4.0-119-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-119
 linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-119-generic
 linux-tools-4.4.0-119
 linux-tools-4.4.0-119-generic
```

My ubuntu is 16.04, 64 bits, running in virtualbox. The host is a dell latitude running ubuntu 14.04.
The compilation went fine, no error.
Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already in the error output. There are some dependancy problems due to linux-tools-common not installed.
So

`sudo apt-get install linux-tools-common`

You may try this before,

`sudo apt-get install -f`